# Post-processing to remove background reflections on bald heads

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, chroma-key

I've done a series of chroma key shots of some co-workers for our website and generally everything came out great, except one of our guys is bald and, well, the green is reflecting onto his head. So, the question is, does anyone know of a good way to remove this sort of highlight in post-processing? I'm using Photoshop CS5.

Comment: It's funny, but the bigger laugh was all of us thought his photo would be the easiest, it took far and away the most work!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's probably several different ways to skin this cat (there always are in Photoshop), and it's be easier to give specific input if there was a picture to look at, but in general I'd probably tackle the problem with something like this:

1. Create a Hue/Saturation Adjustment layer
2. Modify the layer mask such that only the area with bleed problems is selected
3. Pull saturation out of the green out slowly using mostly the 'Greens' channel (Alt+5) and a bit in the Master channel (Alt+2).

As a 'future reference' thing, keeping subjects at least 6 feet from the backdrop will help keep bleed to a minimum.

Comment: 4. make them wear wigs (feel free to downvote me, but i had to say this :D)

Comment: +1 and accepted, it's what I ended up actually figuring out for myself in the end!

Comment: @John: Great minds, and all that... ;-)

Comment: Maybe next time a polarizing filter could help to reduce the reflection.

Comment: + 1 for the note on keeping subjects to at least 6 feet from backdrop.

Answer (score 4):

I also am a make up artist and I say put a little face powder on his head to remove that shine.