# How do I remove reflections from a bald-headed subject in post?

Tags: photo-editing, color-correction

I was asked to take photos at night and this lovely guy had an unfortunate purple/blue light reflecting from the top of his head. How can I edit this please to remove the colour cast?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Rach... the answers to this question may cover you as the essential problem is the same: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9418/post-processing-to-remove-background-reflections-on-bald-heads?rq=1

Comment: The other tip kinda worked but didnt remove all the color but with a bit of 50% clone stamping i think i got there

Comment: @Rach rather than posting the corrected photo in the question, could you please put it in an answer instead? [Stack Exchange explicitly encourages self-answered questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) - thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't work out how to do that?